# How can I insert a button tag into html using Selenium Java?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Is it possible to insert a button element

```
(<button type= "submit">)
```

into the html code of the page using the `driver.execute_script` method?
And how to specify its location?

For example, there is a text field email `(driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//input[@name= 'email']")` and I need to insert the submit button under this field or above this field and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not support such actions.
Selenium is designed to perform actions a real user can do with GUI.
As a user I can't add element into HTML web page.
I can click on element, get element text, scroll page etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is used to testing. So, as per my suggestion there is no need to add anything from Selenium.

If there is no `submit` button, it is surely bug on your page.

So, we suggest you to check once again your page.

[Selenium website link  https://www.selenium.dev/](https://www.selenium.dev/)

Comment: Website has bug 

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is **No**.

But through js you can update an attribute in Selenium. See below.

```
<a href="foo.html" id="foo-id" class="foo-class"> foo-text </a>
```

you can basically update this foo-text to any other string, like :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('foo-id').innerHTML = '201';");
```

also, if you see we have `id` as an `attribute` that has an value `foo-id`, in case you want to update that id to `someotherfoo-id`, you can do as following :-

```
element =  driver.find_element_by_class_name("foo-class");
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('id', 'someotherfoo-id')", element);
```

after this action, you must see the changes in UI. so basically you can do the modification like this.